# directly Download Image by click on Download button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to create wallpapers page for my website. and i want people can download by clicking on download button directly rather than image view in browser and user right click on that and then save as image. is there any solution with java script?

Answer (score 2):

You need to force the content type of the image being sent by the server. There isn't a way to do this client-side.

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=myimage.png
```

Comment: i saw some sites where they handle it with javascript

Comment: @AbdulRauf: If you've found a site that does it, why not view source and use the same technique?

Comment: @AbdulRauf You can make an AJAX request to a server-side file that forces those headers... but it's not client-side code itself that's forcing the image download.

Answer (score 2):

You can force a download via a PHP (or other server-side language) script like this:

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");//notice this content-type, it will force a download since browsers think that's what they should do with .exe files
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ".$file."");
readfile($file);
```

Then in your JavaScript code you can direct users to this script with the GET variable `file` being populated by the JavaScript.

```
$('a.download_link').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();//prevent the normal click action from occuring
    window.location = '/path/to/server-side.php?file=' + encodeURIComponent(this.href);
});
```

This will add a `click` event handler to any links that have the `.download_link` class to direct the browser to the PHP script above to force a download.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a hidden iframe that you set the source attribute on when you click the button.

#### HTML

```
<input class="download" href="http://site.com/imageHandler.ashx" value="Download"/>
```

#### Javascript

```
$("input.download").click(function() { $("iframeID").attr("src", $(this).attr("href")); });
```

You also need to set the content-type using the custom image handler (*whichever server-side language you are using*)

Comment: i have html pages and in that i want to use this option. so with this code i just have to replace the link of my image link with this Http link?

Comment: You cannot use a static link to the image. You need an active script page to assign the content type (*jsp, aspx, asp, php, etc.*).